# Comparação de vetores em C

Tags: c, array

Estou de momento a tentar estabelecer uma comparação de dois vetores em C.

A minha estrutura de código é a seguinte:

```
int iguais(int *v1, int *v2, int tam) {

    int i, cont = 1;
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++) {
        while(*(v1 + i) == *(v2 + i)) {
            cont++;
        }
    }

    return (cont == tam);

}
```

Pode alguém ajudar-me no processo de debugging?

Comment: Agora funcionou.

Comment: Agora eu vi que sempre retorna verdadeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa de dois laços. Se ambos os arrays são do mesmo tamanho basta verificar elemento a elemento se `v1[i] == v2[i]` (a sintaxe de ponteiro é equivalente).

Como otimização, ao invés de contar a quantidade de elementos iguais, vale mais a pena verificar se existe algum elemento diferente (`v1[i] != v2[i]`), retornando falso imediatamente e evitando iterações extras:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool iguais(int *v1, int *v2, int tam) {
    int i, cont = 1;
    for(i=0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (v1[i] != v2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    int v1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int v2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int v3[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6};

    printf("v1 e v2 sao %s\n", iguais(v1, v2, 5) ? "iguais" : "diferentes");
    printf("v1 e v3 sao %s\n", iguais(v1, v3, 5) ? "iguais" : "diferentes");

    return 0;
}
```